# unable to add app engine administrator for emailing

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I want to send emails from my app engine application using one of my Google Apps accounts.  According to the [GAE python docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview.html):

*The From: address can be the email address of a registered administrator (developer) of the application, the current user if signed in with Google Accounts, or any valid email receiving address for the app (that is, an address of the form string@appid.appspotmail.com).*

So I created a user account on my Google Apps domain, no-reply@mydomain.com, to use for outbound email notifications.  However, when I try to add the user as an administrator of the app, it fails with this error:

**Unauthorized**
**You are not authorized to access this application**

Is it possible to configure app engine to send emails using a Google Accounts email address?

Comment: At what step of adding the administrator does it fail with that error?

Answer (score 0):

You must restrict your App Engine app to a Google Apps domain upon initial registration of your App Engine application ID. Unfortunately, this setting can only be set during the initial registration of your app ID.

What you'll need to do is register another application ID, set your authentication option for Google Apps domain, and upload your existing app to the newly registered ID.

Simply going through the "Domain Setup" process in your Dashboard is not enough; you'll only be able to add the app as a service and "host" it using your domain name. To restrict the authorization to your domain only, you'll need to do the first step in the initial registration.

Comment: I re-read the question and not sure if my answer applies. Are you accessing the dev console via https://appengine.google.com/a/yourdomain.com ?

Comment: I am accessing the console this way.  Note that I don't want to restrict usage of the app to members of my domain; will restricting authorization affect that?  I currently perform my own user management using passwords, etc., in my app.

Comment: This is incorrect. All you have to do to use an Apps account as an administrator on an app that uses Google accounts (not Apps accounts) for signin is create a Google account for it at https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount .

Comment: Nick is correct. As mentioned, I misunderstood the question; I thought  Andrew wanted to change the visibility of his application to Apps domain and only allow Apps domain security.

Answer (score 0):

I had also problems adding administrators. In the end, I used a regular gmail account as the sender. Which only works if sending as *@googlemail.com. *.gmail.com fails.